# Line art to SVG path conversion

Tags: gratis, svg, image-conversion

I am looking for a gratis tool Preferably Windows, but Linux is ok, to convert lineart in JPEG or PNG format to SVG, where the lines are defined as SVG `<path>`s.

So, far, so-called conversion tools simply use the `<image>` element. *Technically*, they have converted the image to SVG, but it is of no practical use to me; I need `<path>` elements.

Comment: I presume that you want to avoid that the outline of your original lines are rendered as paths. If yes, you should probably explicitly state so.

Comment: https://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-centerline-tracehttps://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-centerline-trace looks like it could come in useful with that. In my particular case, I wold welcome that. I want to turn a floorplan into SVG `<paths>`s, and separate path for each room is my desire, so inside/outside as two paths would be ideal.